# SQL Loader to load multiple tables from CSV input file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load a CSV file where each row of data is loaded in two  table(TAB1,TAB2) .
   For each row of data in CSV file, one row will be loaded in TAB1  and multiple row in second table.

Example of data row in CSV file :

```
Data_col1,Data_col2,Data_col3,Data_col4   , Key_name1, Key_value1 , Key_name2, Key_value2 ,Key_name3, Key_value3 ,.................
```

I am expecting this data in tables like below :

```
     Tab1
     ====
   Data_col1
   Data_col2
   Data_col3
   Data_col4 

   Tab2  ( Load data in TAB2 until the end of the data row1)                    
      record 1 ==> Key_name1, Key_value1
      record 2 ==> Key_name2, Key_value2
      record 3 ==> Key_name3, Key_value3
```

I did some research but could not solve this issue.
Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Are there ALWAYS 4 data_cols and an unknown number of key name/value pairs in a row as in your example?  It would be helpful if you would edit your post and add to the end a couple of actual data rows and example tables after the rows have been processed to clarify what you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

How about loading into a single import table first and then using a script to process and load the data into two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Typically a situation like this would call for either pre-processing the file to split the records before loading or, as @MercyfulGPF suggested, load to a staging table and run a procedure to process the rows into their tables (this would be my preferred method as it allows you way more control over the process and you could handle variable numbers of key name/value pairs).

However, what you ask for can be done if you have a fixed number of elements and you don't mind a maintenance nightmare.  Construct your control file with multiple "INTO TABLE" sections with the first field starting at position(1).  This forces sqlldr to move it's internal pointer back to the start of the line for each INTO table section, inserting a new row for each one. Each section defines the fields already inserted before it as FILLER in order to skip them (make sure they are not named the same as a table column).  It will not work if there is a variable number of key_name/value pairs as your example suggests though. So this may only be a partial solution but may give you some ideas of what is possible (or not).

```
LOAD DATA
infile datafile.csv 
TRUNCATE

INTO TABLE tab1
fields terminated by ','
( 
 data_col
)

INTO TABLE tab1
fields terminated by ','
( 
 filler1 FILLER position(1)
,data_col
)

INTO TABLE tab1
fields terminated by ','
( 
 filler1 FILLER position(1)
,filler2 FILLER
,data_col
)

INTO TABLE tab1
fields terminated by ','
( 
 filler1 FILLER position(1)
,filler2 FILLER
,filler3 FILLER
,data_col
)

INTO TABLE tab2
fields terminated by ','
( 
 filler1 FILLER position(1)
,filler2 FILLER
,filler3 FILLER
,filler4 FILLER
,key_name
,key_value
)

INTO TABLE tab2
fields terminated by ','
( 
 filler1 FILLER position(1)
,filler2 FILLER
,filler3 FILLER
,filler4 FILLER
,filler5 FILLER
,filler6 FILLER
,key_name
,key_value
)
...
```